# calculating overlap of modular ranges

Tags: algorithms

So, this might be a really simple problem but I can't seem to find a nice algorithm to solve it:

> Given two ranges, *[a1, a2]*, *[b1, b2]*  (all real numbers) and a real number *n*, find the length of the overlapping segment between the two ranges over a modulo of *n*.

For example, consider a **24**-hour clock and the range **[20, 4]** (night time); for a given range, calculate the number of hours within that range that are night hours:

[13, 21] ==> 1 #[20,21]

[0, 6] ==> 4 #[0, 4]

[11, 19] ==> 0

I tried to think of it in terms of predefined segments
[a1,b1], [b2, a2] and do some math with them but it didn't work.
Maybe I should sort them somehow?

I will appreciate any help or direction, thanks!

Comment: What is "the length of the overlapping segment ... over a modulo of $n$"?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus in the clock example it is the total number of hours between the beginning of the range and its end.. |[23, 1]| = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I understand your problem. We have a modulus $n$. A generalized interval $[\![a,b]\!]$ consists of $[a,b]$ if $a < b$, and of $[a,n) \cup [0,b]$ if $a > b$ (assume for simplicity that $a != b$). You want to know the size of the intersection of two generalized intervals $[\![a_1,b_1]\!],[\![a_2,b_2]\!]$.

One way to solve this is to decompose each generalized interval into a disjoint union of one or two intervals, and then compute the size of the pairwise intersections (which I will let you work out yourself), and sum them up.

Comment: eventually I solved it using these assumptions and 7 if-statements, checking whether a1, a2, both or none of them are inside [b1,b2] and then calculating accordingly. Thanks :)